# Discord.js bot to react to its own message after user !command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;
    const gift = ["Gift 1", "Nothing", "Gift 3", "Nothing", "Gift 5", "Nothing", "Gift 7", "Nothing"]

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * gift.length);


    if (commandName === 'gift' && gift[random] === 'Nothing') {
        interaction.reply("No Luck today!");

    } else if (commandName === 'calendar' && gift[random] != 'Nothing') {
        interaction.reply(`Congrats ${interaction.user.username} you won ${gift[random]} !`);
        } 
        
});
```

I would like to make the bot to react to its own answer 'No luck today!' or `Congrats ${interaction.user.username} you won ${gift[random]} !` after someone typed !gift but Interaction doesn't have a .react or .reaction

Any idea how I can manage to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CommandInteraction#reply` returns an instance of `Message`. You can use `.react` there

```js
interaction.reply("No Luck today!").then(m => m.react("emoji"))
```

And for the other message:

```js
interaction.reply(`Congrats ${interaction.user.username} you won ${gift[random]} !`).then(m => m.react("emoji"))
```

Comment: Thank you ! I managed to get to bot to react when the member was doing the !command but not to its own message. Works perfectly now with your solution !